# Run local X11 command from remote SSH connection

Tags: ssh

When I connect to my server using **ssh -X** and run for example **xterm** on the server, the xterm opens up on my local machine.

What I actually want to do is **for the xterm which is installed on the server to open on the server and render on the servers physical display.**. In other words, the same effect if I sat by the server and typed in **xterm** on the servers keyboard.

If I connect to the server skipping the **-X** argument and run xterm, I get:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 
/usr/bin/xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

So I tried to set the **DISPLAY** variable like this:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

but then I get:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
```

How can I run the **xterm** command and make it execute on the servers physical screen?

Comment: There has to be a display open on the localhost by that name AND  you must be authorized to use it.  You probably have to do something manual with xauth, assuming that display exists.

Comment: Notice that `localhost:0.0` and `:0.0` aren't the same. Have you tried `DISPLAY=:0`?

Comment: Starting the `xterm` from an ssh connection and starting it from a local X session won't give the same result unless you get all environment variables to be the same. I find that the easiest way to achieve that is that while I am physically at the machine I open an `xterm` and then start a `screen` command. Later I can ssh to the machine and attach to the `screen` session where I have all the environment variables from the local X session.

Comment: `DISPLAY=:0` is the solution (or the X server needs to listen on tcp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work your server must obviously be running an X server in the first place. Linux servers usually don't have any X server installed, so the presence of an X server on the server is the first thing you have to verify.

Assuming your server is in fact running an X server the most likely explanation is that you are connecting to the X server using the wrong protocol.

There is a difference between `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` and `DISPLAY=:0.0`.

When you write `localhost:0.0` it means the client will resolve the hostname `localhost` and connect to the X server over TCP. The port number is calculated as 6000 plus display number, which here will be 6000 + 0 = 6000.

When you write `:0.0` it means the client will connect to the X server using a unix socket. The advantages of unix sockets are that they are more efficient and access control can be based on uid.

For many years it has been common practice to have TCP disabled by default in X servers and only accept connections over unix sockets. Since you seem to have no specific need for TCP connections I recommend that you just change your command to use unix sockets rather than TCP sockets.

The commands can be abbreviated a little bit as well. This version should work:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xterm &
```

Though this command will work, it will not give you exactly the same result as if you had started `xterm` from the local X session. To achieve the same result you need to ensure that all of the environment variables are the same, not just the `DISPLAY` variable. Desktop environments tend to set a lot of environment variables.

I find that the easiest way to achieve this is to start a `screen` command after logging in to a local X session and then attach to this remotely as needed.

So after logging in I open a terminal and type `screen -xR somename`. Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from it. After logging in remotely I can attach to the screen with `screen -xR somename` and run the commands I needed such as `xterm&` in your case. And once I am done again press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> to detach. This is very useful on desktops when I occasionally have needed to restart `compiz` because it has locked up. I have not yet found any use for this on servers though.

If you didn't start a `screen` command from the local X session in advance and you need to start an X client on the local display from a remote shell, you need to first set all of the environment variables as in the local X session. To do that you can pick the PID of any of the existing X clients in that session and find all the environment variables like this:

```
tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$PID/environ
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, will try it asap I get home, thanks!